# How do you train a singular-output Keras model whose y_pred shape does not match its y_true shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Consider a simple Keras network like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.abs(y_true[0]-y_pred)+K.abs(y_true[1]-y_pred)

def gen():
    while True:
        a = np.random.random()
        b = 2*a
        c = 3*a
        yield (np.array([a]),np.array([b,c]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_dim=1))

model.compile(Adam(lr= 0.01),custom_loss)

model.fit_generator(gen(),steps_per_epoch=20)
```

In this case, it is supposed to learn to predict the average between double and triple the value of its input. y_true is of shape [1], while y_pred is of shape [2]. Therefore, keras throws an error: 'Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2 target samples.' This is by design though, how can you avoid having a bigger target than input array, if you have multiple targets?

Comment: Just don't design that way, there is no single way to train with a smaller output when you have high dim output data, but why would you design your network in this way in thee first place if you know your data shapes?

Comment: In which way can I change the design? Maybe I am just not seeing the obvious, but how can you alter the design to still predict those two different targets?

Comment: If you want it to predict the **average** of `b` and `c`, then you should provide their average as target and not the `b` and `c` themselves!

Comment: This is just an example to show the principle, my actual problem does not allow for that I think. (If you need details, here they are: I am trying to train a unet for image segmentation of noisy images. The two targets the network gets consist of the clean image and the segmentation mask. During training, the loss function is adjusted so that it starts off learning to denoise the image and then, later in training, focus on segmenting the image.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I see in your generator you have single dim- input and 2-dim outputs.

In your loss function, you are indexing in the wrong manner. The first index is usually the batch index, so you have to specify you're trying to calculate the loss across all the batches.

The correct loss implementation would be as below:

`return K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,0])+K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,1])`

I guess you were getting the error because of the improper indexing if this is what you meant then this will solve the problem.

Finally, the number of outputs is determined by the units in the last layer. [Look at your model summary, you'll see the last layer has shape `(None,1)`, but you need `(None, 2)` there as you have 2 outputs] You can look into your model summary, you are passing two values b, c in your generator but your model has one output (1 unit in the final dense layer). It's as easy as changing the units in Dense (2) to fix this.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as K

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    print(y_true.shape)
    print(y_pred.shape)
    return K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,0])+K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,1])
    return K.keras.losses.mse(y_true, y_pred) # this one works

def gen():
    while True:
        a = np.random.random()
        b = 2*a
        c = 3*a
        yield (np.array([a]),np.array([b,c]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2,input_dim=1))

model.compile('adam',custom_loss)

model.summary()

model.fit_generator(gen(),steps_per_epoch=20)
```

```
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 4         
=================================================================
Total params: 4
Trainable params: 4
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
(None, 1)
(None, 2)
(None, 1)
(None, 2)
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.8827

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f48e64f1d68>
```

Comment: Changing the loss implementation definitely is necessary, but did not get rid of the error for me. In this dummy example, I am trying to get a model that predicts the average between 2x and 3x the input, giving the Dense Layer two outputs will cause the model to predict 2x and 3x seperately on two different nodes.

Comment: Okay, first thing first. The error should definitely go away. What error you're facing now?

Comment: I had to adjust the loss implementation from `return K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,0])+K.abs(y_true[:,:]-y_pred[:,1])` from your comment to `return K.abs(y_true[:,0]-y_pred[:,:])+K.abs(y_true[:,1]-y_pred[:,:]` but that is a minor thing I messed up in my original comment too, I've corrected it now. After that change, it still gives the same error as before.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the error message as I suggested, also I ran the code in google colab, add the error + your system details (tensorflow version) to the question.

Comment: I still get `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2 target samples.`. I did not give the dense layer two nodes as suggested though, because that that would predict the two different targets on two different nodes, instead of predicting the average of the two numbers on one node. I am running tensorflow 1.15 and keras 2.2.5, if that helps.

Comment: Are you using my code? It seems you're still using your code. I'm using tensorflow 2.0 by the way.

Comment: I am running your version of the code. even with two nodes on the dense layer it still gives the same error. I wonder if it's actually a matter of tensorflow versions.

Comment: I've now copy pasted your code into Google Colab, which is running 2.2.0 as well, but it still gave the same eroor message. Maybe I'm just cursed ;)

Comment: Try this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A8edGYyFuE7d1Z-ZJusz5zU_7yCevF2L

Comment: Got it, thanks! It works, even though I find it a bit unfortunate one has to use two nodes (and therefore also train double the weights needed) even though only one really would be needed to accomplish the same thing.